# Image Capture - Possible Data Loss when Downloading?

Tags: macos, iphone

tl;dr: When downloading media from an iPhone via Image Capture, what guarantees, if any, are there that the photos, videos, etc. actually downloaded without any corruption?

I should say that I have a sneaking suspicion that I am being paranoid because I can't find any info about this online. This lack of complaints leads me to suspect that there is no reason to be concerned. However, this is balanced by the knowledge that most people do not concern themselves with data protection and a few corrupted files could easily go overlooked during a bulk download of hundreds or thousands.

Comment: Is this about security or about protection? Also, are you trying to debug a practical problem, or is the question rather hypothetical?

Comment: Hmm, I'm guessing "protection" better captures data loss? I've edited the question. There is a practical problem, but it's tangential to this particular issue. I want to sync my iPhone media with a QNAP NAS, but their iPhone mounting is infuriatingly buggy, so I gave up and I'm using Image Capture as a first step to get the photos/videos off the phone. My question is that, since there doesn't seem to be a practical way to directly access the files on the phone, it would simplify the workflow if I could assume that the result of Image Capture perfectly mirrors the phone.

Comment: I would assume that any widespread form of data corruption would make the news very quick. At the end it‘s a data transfer between computers.